# FactoryGirl causing NoMethodError after upgrading Rails to 4.2.3+

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

I've just upgraded my app from Rails 4.2.0 to 4.2.5, and suddenly ***all*** my tests (well, 292 of 307) are failing with messages like this one:

```
 Failure/Error: let(:org)     { create :organisation }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/test_after_commit-0.4.0/lib/test_after_commit.rb:57:in `sync_with_transaction_state'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:86:in `new_record?'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `block in make_lambda'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:227:in `call'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:227:in `block (2 levels) in halting_and_conditional'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:227:in `each'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:227:in `all?'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:227:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `call'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block in call'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `each'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `call'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_initialize_callbacks'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/core.rb:284:in `initialize'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/decorator/new_constructor.rb:9:in `new'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/decorator.rb:14:in `send'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/decorator.rb:10:in `method_missing'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/decorator/invocation_tracker.rb:11:in `method_missing'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/decorator.rb:14:in `send'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/decorator.rb:10:in `method_missing'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/configuration.rb:15:in `block in initialize'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:48:in `instance_exec'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:48:in `build_class_instance'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:13:in `object'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:12:in `object'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:42:in `run'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:23:in `block in run'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:22:in `run'
 # /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@engagement-hub-rails/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:20:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
 # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/channels_controller_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/channels_controller_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/channels_controller_spec.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

As you can see, I'm using Ruby 2.1.4, Rails 4.2.5, FactoryGirl 4.5.0, and RSpec 3.3.0. I've been playing around with these versions - Ruby 2.2.2 doesn't help, FactoryGirl and RSpec are already up-to-date; and the error occurs in Rails >= 4.2.3.

The Rails version (and the gems it uses) is the *only* change I've made to my repository, and everything was working perfectly until I did. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing it's related to [this change to the test_after_commit gem](https://github.com/grosser/test_after_commit/commit/2c02a10d9f1fd0a2c12d44c54f39139fc7123dd4). Try updating `test_after_commit` to the latest version (0.4.2).